# Nested structures in Golang - Struct A in struct B and struct B in struct A

Tags: go, struct, graph, concurrency

I have to create two structures that contain each other.
There is a compiler error because the RoutingTable structure cannot be used as a type until it is declared.

is it possible to declare them "at the same time"?

```
type Node struct 
    {
    name             string
    engaged          bool
    visited_packages[]int
    rt              []RoutingTable
    }

type RoutingTable struct 
    {
    next_hop        Node
    cost            int
    }
```

[my error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aElvW.png)

[my code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esi6y.png)

Comment: The error doesn't stem from "RoutingTable structure cannot be used as a type until it is declared" but from the resulting memory layout being infinitely large. Use pointers, either for both or at least one.

Comment: @Volker is right, Use pointers  ```next_hop        *Node```

Comment: There's no problem with the code in the question, see https://play.golang.org/p/45jmYUnX9On. If you truly have a problem, then you should post the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I put my structures' declarations in main function, when I put it outside it it started to work